# How to solve npm error “npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE” showing in heroku logs

Tags: node.js, heroku

```
 2021-01-10T12:11:24.995125+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:291

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995144+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995145+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995145+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995147+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995148+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995148+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995149+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995149+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995150+00:00 app[web.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995150+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995151+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995151+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection._handleProtocolError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995152+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.emit (events.js:314:20)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995152+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._delegateError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995153+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:116:8)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995153+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995154+00:00 app[web.1]:     [... lines matching original stack trace ...]

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995154+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995154+00:00 app[web.1]:   fatal: true,

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995155+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'

2021-01-10T12:11:24.995155+00:00 app[web.1]: }

2021-01-10T12:11:25.020173+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2021-01-10T12:11:25.020807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1

2021-01-10T12:11:25.030545+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! nodejs-mysql@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`

2021-01-10T12:11:25.030797+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1

2021-01-10T12:11:25.031095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 

2021-01-10T12:11:25.031342+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs-mysql@1.0.0 start script.

2021-01-10T12:11:25.031671+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2021-01-10T12:11:25.042941+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2021-01-10T12:11:25.043471+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2021-01-10T12:11:25.044289+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-10T12_11_25_032Z-debug.log

2021-01-10T12:11:25.130164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2021-01-10T12:11:25.175817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

2021-01-10T12:11:33.663572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=teemp-app-abhi.herokuapp.com request_id=2a7e9470-a0fb-401e-87df-113ea127f60f fwd="103.226.226.62" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: explain inside the question and not in the Headline

Comment: Do you push the npm folder to heroku?

Comment: https://github.com/Tesla-gamer/heroku

Comment: YES I pushed the npm folder to heroku

Comment: i am going to deploy my app again without the node module folder

Comment: @Abishek gupta  Has it worked?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Don't push the `node_modules` folder to Heroku because Heroku will install all your dependencies.

If you are on a unix based system

1. open up a terminal
2. go to your projects directory
3. `rm -rf node_modules`